# Shiny for Python: Can't get tabs to work in my app | NotImplementedError( NotImplementedError: nav() items must appear within navset_*() container

Tags: python, python-3.x, py-shiny

so I'm trying to make an app with two tabs, tab 1 has a table with a filter and tab 2 has a plot from that data with the same filter. However, I keep getting this error and can't figure it out:

File "/Users/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/shiny/ui/*navs.py", line 84, in tagify
raise NotImplementedError(
NotImplementedError: nav() items must appear within navset**() container.

The code is below:

```
'''
#Scatterplot function
def create_scatter_plot(data, x_var, y_var, **kwargs):
         # Create a scatter plot using plotly.express
         fig = px.scatter(data, x=x_var, y=y_var, **kwargs)

         return fig

app_ui = ui.page_fluid(
    # Display your DataFrame in a tab 
    ui.navset_tab(
        #shinyswatch.theme.darkly(),
        ui.nav(
            ui.panel_title("Table"),
            ui.layout_sidebar(
                ui.panel_sidebar(
                    ui.input_selectize(id="cell_line", label="Cell Line", choices=cell_lines, selected='CTR-M2-O5', multiple=True)),
                ui.panel_main("Raw Data", ui.HTML(DT(df, classes = "display nowrap compact", 
                                      column_filters = "footer" )))
             ),
        ui.nav(
            ui.panel_title("Plot"),
            ui.layout_sidebar(
                ui.panel_sidebar(
                    ui.input_selectize(id="cell_line", label="Cell Line", choices=cell_lines, selected='CTR-M2-O5', multiple=True)),
                ui.panel_main(
                    ui.output_plot("Plot", ui.HTML(create_scatter_plot(df, x_var = cell_lines, y_var = fold_changes)))),
                 )
        #ui.nav("Plot", ui.HTML(create_scatter_plot(df)))  
        #ui.nav("Plot", ui.HTML(px(df)))
             )
         )
     )
)
'''
```

Any help you can provide me in solving this would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving this error because you placed the second `ui.nav` element inside the first `ui.nav` element when they should be siblings.

```py
app_ui = ui.page_fluid(
    ui.navset_tab(
        ui.nav(
            ui.panel_title("Table"),
            ui.layout_sidebar(
                ui.panel_sidebar(
                    ui.input_selectize(id="cell_line", label="Cell Line", choices=cell_lines, selected='CTR-M2-O5', multiple=True)),
                ui.panel_main("Raw Data", ui.HTML("<p>abc</p>"))
                )
            ), # missing closing parenthesis
        ui.nav(
            ui.panel_title("Plot"),
            ui.layout_sidebar(
                ui.panel_sidebar(
                    ui.input_selectize(id="cell_line", label="Cell Line", choices=cell_lines, selected='CTR-M2-O5', multiple=True)),
                ui.panel_main(
                    ui.output_plot("Plot"),
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

Also, if the filter items are common to both tabs, you should probably wrap the sidebar layout outside the tabs. This way, you only have one `input_selectize`, and its `id` is unique (as it should be).

```py
app_ui = ui.page_fluid(
    ui.layout_sidebar(
        ui.panel_sidebar(
            # element with unique id
            ui.input_selectize(id="cell_line", label="Cell Line", choices=cell_lines, selected='CTR-M2-O5', multiple=True)),
        ui.panel_main(
            ui.navset_tab(
                ui.nav(
                    ui.panel_title("Table"),
                    ui.panel_main("Raw Data", ...)
                    ),
                ui.nav(
                    ui.panel_title("Plot"),
                    ui.output_plot("Plot"),
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
```